# Javascript promise not waiting to resolve before then

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, promise, async-await

I'm writing javascript code to parse a huge file (several GBs) and I'm using FileReader's readAsArrayBuffer function with promises (see below):

```
        function readRaw(fc, length) {
            const fileReader = new FileReader();

            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                fileReader.onloadend = function(value) {
                    console.log("onloadend");
                    fc.offset += length;
                    resolve(new Uint8Array(value.result));
                }
                fileReader.onerror = (err) => {
                    console.error(err);
                    reject(err);
                }

                const slice = fc.handle.slice(fc.offset, fc.offset + length);
                fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(slice);
            });
        }

        function parsefile(file) {
            let fc = { handle: file, offset: 0 };
            let buffer = {};

            var promise = readRaw(fc, 32);

            promise.then(function(value) {
                console.log("success: offset=" + fc.offset)
                buffer = value
            }).catch((e) => {
                console.error(e);
            });

            console.log("offset=" + fc.offset);
        }

        document
            .getElementById('fileToRead')
            .addEventListener('change', function () {
                let file = this.files[0];

                if (file) {
                    parsefile(file);
                }
            }, false);
```

My expectation is that `Promise.prototype.then()` should wait for the promise to resolve before continuing but I'm not able to get it to work no matter how I tweak the code or switch to use async/await.

**Expected:**

```
onloadend
success: offset=32
offset=32
```

**Actual**

```
offset=0
onloadend
success: offset=32
```

Thanks in advance for any help and enlightenment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [Why await beats Promise.then(...)](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/async-stack-traces)"

> The fundamental difference between await and vanilla promises is that `await X()` suspends execution of the current function, while `promise.then(X)` continues execution of the current function after adding the X call to the callback chain.